# Sum of not necessarily independent discrete random variables.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let ${X_k}$ be a sequence of discrete random variables, where $P(X_k=k)=\frac{1}{k^2}$ and $P(X_k=0)=1-\frac{1}{k^2}$. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Does $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{\log n}}\rightarrow 0$ (in any sense; a.e., in prob, or in dist.)? Using Borel Cantelli lemma I can show that $P(\{X_i\neq 0\} \text{ i.o.})=0$, but I do not how to go from there (I do not think that this implies $P(\{S_n\neq 0\} \text{ i.o.})=0$).

Comment: Since $P(\{X_i\neq 0\} \text{ i.o.})=0$, $X_i=0$ almost surely for every $i$ large enough, in particular $(S_n)$ is almost surely bounded hence indeed $S_n/a_n\to0$ almost surely for every sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\to\infty$.

Comment: It does make sense that $P(\{X_i\neq 0\}\text{ i.o.})=0$ implies that $P(\{S_n\text{ is bounded\}})=1$, but is there a rigorous way to show this, or it is straight forward?

Comment: The complement of $\{X_i\ne0\ \text{i.o.}\}$ is $\{X_i=0\ \text{finitely many times}\}$. This is all the rigorous proof one needs.

Comment: (In the last comment, isn't it $\neq$ in the second event?)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I think you are right. I think it is just a typo.